# Angular 9 Copy to clipboard with string concatenation

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm struggling with a problem. I want to create a copy to clipboard functionality. This is my code:

```
public copyUrlToClipboard(inputElement) {
        inputElement.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
```

that works great, but I have a problem. I would like to concatenate string from this input with another string value, before it invokes an 'copy' exec command. It should concatenate previously set string to the begin of this input value. Is it possible to make it this way?

Thanks!

Comment: what is another string value?

Comment: it can be something like: `http://test.com/something/` and after that I would like to add value from this input and copy to clipboard the whole string like:
`http://test.com/something/thisisvaluefrominput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options. The first is to use external library, like clipboard.js or something like that.

The second option is to dynamic create an element, which will be filled programically, and you'll select this input, then execute command.

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
input.value = yourPrefix + yourValueFromInput; // (hope you have 2-way binding, so you'll have values in variables)
input.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
```